# Angular .queryParams.subscribe always returns undefined

Tags: angular

I was trying to find the difference between .snapshot and .queryParam in angular for the same i created a demo with the component code as follows

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import{ActivatedRoute,ParamMap, Router} from '@angular/router'

@Component({
  selector: 'app-routing-eg',
  templateUrl: './routing-eg.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./routing-eg.component.css']
})
export class RoutingEgComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private _route : ActivatedRoute,private router:Router) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    const id =   this._route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');
    let par:any;
    this._route.queryParams.subscribe((params) =>{
        par = params['id'];
    })
    console.log('id' + id)
    console.log('par' + par)
    this.router.navigate(['routed/:2'])
    console.log('id 2 ' + id)
    console.log('par 2' + par)
  }

}
```

the output that i get for the above code is

```
id1
parundefined
id 2 1
par 2undefined
```

Where would i be going wrong that i recieve undefined when i use subscribe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
const id = this._route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');
```

I think you are trying to get `params` not `queryParams`.

You should subscribe to `params`. And move your console.log for `par` variable inside the subscription because it's asynchronous.

```js
this._route.params.subscribe((params) => {
  par = params['id'];
  console.log('par' + par);
});
this.router.navigate(['routed/:2']);
```

Answer (score 0):

The `par` variable is assigned asynchronously. As such, any statements that directly depend it's new state should be inside the subscription. Because by the time you're logging it, it isn't assigned any values yet.

```js
  ngOnInit(): void {
    const id =   this._route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');
    let par:any;
    this._route.queryParams.subscribe((params) =>{
        par = params['id'];
        console.log('par' + par)
        this.router.navigate(['routed/:2'])
        console.log('par 2' + par)
    })
    console.log('id' + id)
    console.log('id 2 ' + id)
  }
```

With the above statements, you might observe that the `id` logs are printed before the `par` logs. More info on asynchronous data [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14220321/6513921).

Comment: still same ,but if i use params instead of queryParam i do get a value ,why so?

Comment: @SwarupChavan, queryParams and params are not the same concept